# FabricJS can't maintain the width of the original image after replacing it

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying replace images on the canvas after editing it. I need to maintain the width and height of the original image after replacing it, this is my code :

it replaces the image with the new image to the original height and width of the old image as expected.  But if I make some changes to old image and then replace the image the changes are not applied.

I want all the changes made on the old image like its height width and angle to be applied to new image

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(JSON.parse(json_data), canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), function(o, object) {
  if (object.type == 'image') {
    var current_width = object.width;
    var current_height = object.height;

    object.setSrc(url, function() {
      // method#1
      object.scaleToWidth(current_width);
      object.scaleToHeight(current_height);
      canvas.renderAll();
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
obj.set({
 width: current_width,
 height: current_height
})
```

Just set width and height no need to use `scaleToWidth` and `scaleToHeight`.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1');
fabric.Image.fromURL("https://picsum.photos/200/300?random", function(oImg) {
  oImg.set({
    left: 30,
    top: 30
  })
  canvas.add(oImg);
});

function changeSrc() {
  var json_data = canvas.toJSON();
  canvas.loadFromJSON(json_data, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), function(o, object) {
    if (object.type == 'image') {
      var current_width = object.width;
      var current_height = object.height;
      object.setSrc("https://i.imgur.com/4yOoOzl.jpg", function(obj) {
        obj.set({
          width: current_width,
          height: current_height
        })
        canvas.renderAll();
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```css
canvas {
 border:1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<button onclick="changeSrc()">Change Src</button>
<canvas id="canvas1" width="400" height="400" style=""></canvas>
```